# Recreating MS Windows Phone Tiltin Animation in CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms, keyframe

I am trying to get the "tilt-in" animation working on a little project of mine using CSS animations. Unfortunately I have not been able to port it from the MS Demo where - doubtlessly all the code is there: http://m.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/demo/default.aspx#home

I'm trying to get the tiles to fade in when the page is loaded, just that part. Once is absolutely fine. I understand that I need to define the vendor keyframes, but my attempts have been so poor that I am not pasting them in my example in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qCQQD/2/

Anyone out there who'll help me out? That would be beyond awesome!

EDIT 1:

a) I'm still trying to get the rotateRight animation running when the page is loaded. I've probably got a hacky version with leftRotate in the .tile class and that removed (and rightRotate added) on pageload.

b) This

```
.tile:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.97);
    -o-transform: scale(0.97);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.97);
    transform: scale(0.97);
}
```

got super slow in Chrome because of the code added, how can I get it back to normal?

I suspect it takes some sort of timeframe from the #tile

```
-webkit-transition: 300ms 160ms;
```

It looks like a slow motion right now. I'm going to try adding something like -webkit-transition: 50ms to it. (yeah I know, total noob).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically like this.  You have it set up fairly correctly, but you just need to actually change some settings.  Check this jsfiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qCQQD/4/) out.

I'm only using javascript to add a class or remove a class.  You could simply do that sort of stuff on a :hover tag in css also it would do the same thing.

I mainly just modified your css to include a rotate(90deg) -webkit-transition.  Therefore this will only work in chrome and probably safari.  If you want it to work in firefox then you'll have to do the -moz-transition for the rotation.

Comment: Sweet, that looks great @jeschafe.

Comment: Two more things @jeschafe: Now I'm still trying to have them fade in when the page is loaded. I tried this  `$(window).load(function() { $(".tile").addClass("rightRotate"); });` but this might not work since the tiles are already there when the page is loaded? 2) This `#tile1 { -webkit-transform-origin-x: -8px; -webkit-transition: 300ms 0ms;}` is now affecting my tile's active state's responsiveness, how can I get it back (`.tile:active { -webkit-transform: scale(0.97); -moz-transform: scale(0.97); }`)?

Comment: Correct the tiles are already there when the page is loaded.  I think you might need to read up on CSS3 transitions a bit.  Basically once you put a transition (-moz or -webkit)  it affects almost any style change and will try to animate it.  I've created another demo for you that does it onload.  I'm not sure what you mean by `is now affecting my tile's active state's responsiveness, how can I get it back (.tile:active { -webkit-transform: scale(0.97); -moz-transform: scale(0.97); }`

Comment: @jescafe. Thank you I've had more or less the same effect, it works quite decently. There's no surprise, no one would understand those words. Check out the edit in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Strangely, there is no such animation in Firefox 35.